# How to adjust a UITextView to not clip the top row?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextview

UITextViews can be scrolled by user gestures so that some rows of text might be only partially visible.

Is it possible to adjust the positioning of text in a UITextView so that the top visible row of characters is not clipped (ie partially obscured above the top of the view rectangle)?  Perhaps by smoothly scrolling up or down by a fraction of a line height some time after user interaction has ended?  If so, how?

Comment: you have to do the math, and check/adjust scroll position after each scroll. For example, `if` scrollposition < 5 `then` scroll to 0. Depending on the content, you can specify some height that should never be clipped, and see if scrollposition is a multiple of it, otherwise scroll to the nearest height. Also pls show what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
let attributes = [
NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraph,
NSFontAttributeName: font,
NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: -5
```

]

I think you should write these lines to bound.